# Where is Document class textbox in flash cs3?

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs3

In a tutorial I find a statement "In the Document Class text box in the Property inspector of flash document, write Test1" But i didnt find that document class textbox. Im using flash CS3. Where it is. Please Help.

Answer (score 4):

If you click on an empty spot on the stage with the arrow (selection) tool, the PI will change to basic document properties. One of the items in the PI will be a text box where you can specify the document class. You can also get to this setting by going into the Flash tab of your publish settings and selecting the ActionScript 3 button. Also, you must be publishing to ActionScript3 to see either of these text boxes.